# Display Table Values Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, common-table-expression

I have a dropdown list that is imported with data from a table in a database. The dropdown values consist of a value MR_ID that is concatenated with MR_Name that is located in a different table. Depending on what is selected, I want to display a table that shows the necessary information that correlates to what was selected in the dropdown list. So, for example, if I select "1 - Company A" in the dropdown list, I want the Supp_ID values (can be more than 1 value) that correlate to the "1 - Company A" value to be displayed in a table. How can I do this?

The table is only 2 columns, MR_ID (which is what is displayed in the dropdown list) and Supp_ID.

I had this working before but I had to change my queries to use CTE instead and it threw me off.

Here were my original queries on my main page and also the query that the ajax calls...

```
// Query on main page
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index";

// Query that is used in ajax call (test-table.php)
$sql_one = "SELECT CAST(Supp_ID AS INT) AS Supp_ID, CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index WHERE MR_ID = '$mr_id'";
```

Here are my new queries using CTE that I cant figure out how to get them working...

```
// Query on main page
$sql = "WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', Stage_Rebate_Master.MR_Name) AS MR_ID
    , Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID AS sort_column
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index
LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master
ON Stage_Rebate_Master.MR_ID=Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID
)
SELECT MR_ID
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    sort_column;";

// Query that is used in ajax call (test-table.php)
$sql_one = "WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', Stage_Rebate_Master.MR_Name) AS MR_ID
    , Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID AS sort_column, CAST(Stage_Rebate_Index.Supp_ID as INT) AS Supp_ID
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index
LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master
ON Stage_Rebate_Master.MR_ID=Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID
)
SELECT MR_ID, Supp_ID
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    MR_ID = '$mr_id'
ORDER BY
    sort_column;";
```

This is my ajax along with a line of code that brings in the $_POST value...

```
// Reads what the user selects from the drop down list and displays table when a selection is made
function updatetable(myForm) {

    function show() { document.getElementById('index-table').style.display = 'block'; }


    var selIndex = myForm.selectedIndex;
    console.log();
    var selName = $( "#mr_id option:selected" ).text();

// Ajax sends POST method to Stage_Rebate_Index table and pulls information based on drop down selection
$.ajax ({
    url: "test-table.php",
    method: "POST", //can be post or get, up to you
    data: {
        mr_id : selName
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        //Might want to delete table and put a loading screen, otherwise ignore this
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#table_div").html(data); // table_div is the div you're going to put the table into, and 'data' is the table itself.
    }
 });

}
```

$_POST method brought in on same script as the query that is used in ajax call...

```
$mr_id = $_POST['mr_id'];
```

Comment: Are you having an error, a timeout or something?...can you add that information to your questions?

Comment: Please show what the AJAX call is returning, if anything.  Also... you're not defining which file is `test-table.php` and what your `echo` statement provides.

Comment: @Hackerman there is no error or anything...when i select a value from the dropdown, i want the corresponding values to display in a table. The only thing that displays currently when a value is selected are the table headings....no actual data

Comment: @DevlshOne I added in my comments in the code which queries are on the test-table.php script...my echo statement is currently providing nothing as the only thing displaying once i select a value are the table headers, as I had told Hackerman

Comment: I'm thinking it has to be something minor....maybe with the $_POST method code...because if i comment out the CTE queries and use my original ones, then it works great! Except then its not concatenated or sorted with ORDER BY and I need that